# Pythonic way to find highest values (and indexes) in list

Tags: python, sorting, indexing, ranking

I have a list of integers and I want to find the highest values (maximum and closest) in the list and their corresponding index values.

I have one method but I feel that it's too convoluted!

```
lst = [10,6,17,99,3,1,-3,47, 99]
max_value = (max(lst))
largest = 0.0
largest_index = 0
second_largest = 0.0
second_largest_index = 0
third_largest = 0
third_largest_index = 0
for (index,value) in enumerate (lst):
        if value == largest_value:
            if largest == 0.0:
                largest = value
                largest_index = index
            elif largest != 0.0 and value > second_largest:
                second_largest = value
                second_largest_index= index
            elif second_largest != 0.0 and value > third_largest:
                third_largest = value
                third_largest_index = index
            elif third_largest != 0.0 and value > third_largest:
                fourth_largest = value
                fourth_largest_index = index

        elif value > second_largest and value < largest_value:
            second_largest = value
            second_largest_index = index
        elif value > third_largest and value < second_largest:
            third_largest = value
            third_largest_index = index
        elif value > fourth_largest and value < third_largest:
            fourth_largest = value
            fourth_largest_index = index
    indexlist = [largest_index, second_largest_index, third_largest_index, fourth_largest_index]
return indexlist
```

Because the list may have duplicate values (which I want to retain), it might be that the four largest values end up being "a,a,b,c". So I'm trying to find both the maximum values and the second/third/etc highest values at the same time.

As I'm trying to find the index values, I don't think that sorting the list would help. Is there a way to retain the index of the original list so that it also gets modified if I sort the list from highest to lowest?

Edit for clarity: It might be the case that I have [99,95, 50, 90,99] (multiple occurences of maximum value) or [99, 70, 70, 90,50]. What I'm trying to do is find the highest values - potentially but not necessarily multiple occurences of a maximum value.

Comment: Do you wish to return the index of the first-found largest number in the list? How many largest numbers can there even be?

Comment: @534 How many max values do you want? Is it always the same?

Comment: also, please do not ever use 'list' as a variable name since it is a built-in type in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (maybe overkill) solution but quite clean would be:

```
lst = [10, 6, 17, 99, 3, 1, -3, 47, 99]
meta_lst = list(enumerate(lst))
```

and then sort by the value (which is the second element)

```
from operators import itemgetter
sorted_meta_lst = sorted(meta_lst, key=itemgetter(1))
```

You will have a increasing succession of pairs (index in list, value).

Answer (score 5):

Create an iterable of tuples of value and index (in that order) and sort that. Sorting tuples is done on the first element (and if equal, on the second, and so on):

```
sorted(((value, index) for index, value in enumerate(list_of_values)), reverse=True)
```

In your example, the output is:

```
[(99, 8), (99, 3), (47, 7), (17, 2), (10, 0), (6, 1), (3, 4), (1, 5), (-3, 6)]
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you want something like this (very fast - doesn't require sorting so runs in *`O(n)`*):

```
>>> lst = [10, 6, 17, 99, 3, 1, -3, 47, 99] # avoid using "list"
>>> max_value = max(lst) # get max value
>>> max_index = lst.index(max_value) # get its index
>>> max_index, max_value
(3, 99)
```

And if you need the index of **all** the occurrences of the highest values:

```
>>> max_value = max(lst)
>>> [i for i, j in enumerate(lst) if j == max_value]
[3, 8]
```

And combined with their values:

```
>>> [(i,j) for (i, j) in enumerate(lst) if j == max_value]
[(3, 99), (8, 99)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way: create a tuple of values-index pairs, sort the tuple using the values and choose the nth first (or last) values:

```
mylist = [10,6,17,99,3,1,-3,47, 99]
tup = zip(mylist, range(len(mylist)))
sorted_list = sorted(tup, key=lambda v: v[0], reverse=True)
print sorted_list[:4] # [(99, 3), (99, 8), (47, 7), (17, 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A: create new list of tuples that stores original indexes and values

B: sort that list high to low

C: take 4 highest elements

D: use them

```
list_is_a_bad_name = [10,6,17,99,3,1,-3,47, 99]
the_list_with_indexes = [(idx, i) for idx, i in  enumerate(list_is_a_bad_name)]
sorted_list = sorted(the_list_with_indexes, reverse=True, key=lambda i:i[1])

for i in sorted_list[:4]:
    print("{} - {}".format(i[0], i[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to find the largest number:

```
l = [10,6,17,99,3,1,-3,47, 99]
max_id, max_no = max(enumerate(l), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

For largest `k` numbers, you can use the [heapq](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) module:

```
from heapq import nlargest
l = [10,6,17,99,3,1,-3,47, 99]
k = 3
nmax = nlargest(k, enumerate(a), key=lambda x:x[1])  # returns list of (index, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = [10,6,17,99,3,1,-3,47, 99]
maximum = max(mylist)
print maximum, [i for i, j in enumerate(mylist) if j == maximum]

99 [3, 8]
```

Works in python 2.7

or

```
import heapq
print heapq.nlargest(len(mylist), enumerate(mylist),  key=lambda x: x[1])
[(3, 99), (8, 99), (7, 47), (2, 17), (0, 10), (1, 6), (4, 3), (5, 1), (6, -3)]
```

Also works in python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Collect the indexes as you go through the lsit:

```
lst = [10,6,17,99,3,1,-3,47, 99]
best = lst[0]
idxlst = [0]
for k,v in enumerate(lst[1:]):
    if (v > best):
        best = v
        idxlst = [k+1]
    elif (v == best):
        idxlst.append(k+1)
```